# Trouble with focusedproperty() listener

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

I wrote an application that consists of the following [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtRij.png)
The goal of the application is to add a blue rectangle on a canvas to the black pane on the left. Therefore I wrote a Class Preview (which also holds the black Pane)

```
public class Preview
{
    Canvas can=new Canvas();
    GraphicsContext gc=can.getGraphicsContext2D();
    Pane canvas=new Pane();

    int WIDTH=1920;
    int HEIGHT=1080;
    int y=50;

    public Node area()
    {
       BorderPane container=new BorderPane();
       ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane(can);
       sp.setFitToHeight(true);
       sp.setFitToWidth(true);

       sp.setStyle("-fx-background: black;");
       container.setCenter(sp);
       return container;
    }

    public void placeCanvas()
    {
        can.setHeight(100);
        can.setWidth(100);
        gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        gc.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
        canvas.getChildren().add(can);
    }
}
```

I created a preview object in my GUI class. When I try to call `preview.placeCanvas()` in my GUI class, it works as expected an produces a [blue rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txnV4.png)
However, the end goal is to have the rectangle appeaer when the top textfield ("title") looses focus.

```
//Layout of Application
    root.setCenter(preview.area());
    root.setRight(sp);
    root.setBottom(btns);

    //preview.placeCanvas();

    title.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, outFocus, inFocus) ->
    {
        if(outFocus)
        {
            preview.placeCanvas();
            Alert placed=new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION,"Placed Canvas!",ButtonType.OK);
            placed.showAndWait();
        }   
    });
```

when I run the above code, the Alert pops up, which tells me, that I entered the if statement, but I see [no blue rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2J8i.png)

An help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. if anybody is interested in reproducing the problem, below is the complete code of application :)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Separator;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GUI extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage frame) throws Exception 
    {   
        VBox main=new VBox();
        ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane(main);

        Label header=new Label();
        Label performers=new Label();
        Label crew=new Label();

        TextField title=new TextField();
        TextField subtitle=new TextField();
        TextField roleLabel=new TextField();
        TextField role=new TextField();
        TextField actor=new TextField();
        TextField crewLabel=new TextField();
        TextField job=new TextField();
        TextField name=new TextField();

        Button save=new Button("Speichern ->");
        Button clear=new Button("Clear");

        BorderPane head=new BorderPane();
        BorderPane performersPane=new BorderPane();
        BorderPane crewPane=new BorderPane();
        BorderPane btns=new BorderPane();

        GridPane performersGrid=new GridPane();
        GridPane crewGrid=new GridPane();

        ColumnConstraints col1=new ColumnConstraints();
        ColumnConstraints col2=new ColumnConstraints();
        col1.setPercentWidth(60);

        //Preview Area
        Preview preview=new Preview();

        //Root Pane
        BorderPane root=new BorderPane();

        frame.setTitle("End Credits Generator");

        //VBox Elements
        header.setText("Titel/Untertitel");
        title.setPromptText("Titel des Films eingeben");
        subtitle.setPromptText("Untertitel des Films eingeben");

        performers.setText("Schauspieler");
        roleLabel.setPromptText(performers.getText()+" ändern");
        role.setPromptText("Name des Schauspieler eingeben");
        actor.setPromptText("Name des Schauspieler eingeben");

        crew.setText("Crew");
        crewLabel.setPromptText(crew.getText()+" ändern");
        job.setPromptText("Name des Departments eingeben");
        name.setPromptText("Name der Mitarbeiter eingeben");

        BorderPane.setAlignment(header,Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(header,new Insets(5,0,5,0));
        BorderPane.setMargin(title,new Insets(5,0,5,0));
        BorderPane.setMargin(subtitle,new Insets(5,0,5,0));
        head.setTop(header);
        head.setCenter(title);
        head.setBottom(subtitle);

        performersGrid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1,col2);
        GridPane.setHalignment(performers,HPos.CENTER);
        performersGrid.add(performers,0,0);
        performersGrid.add(roleLabel,1,0);
        performersGrid.add(role,0,1,2,1);
        performersGrid.add(actor,0,2,2,1);
        performersPane.setCenter(performersGrid);

        crewGrid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1,col2);
        GridPane.setHalignment(crew,HPos.CENTER);
        crewGrid.add(crew,0,0);
        crewGrid.add(crewLabel,1,0);
        crewGrid.add(job,0,1,2,1);
        crewGrid.add(name,0,2,2,1);
        crewPane.setCenter(crewGrid);

        btns.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        btns.setRight(save);
        btns.setLeft(clear);

        //Layout of VBox
        main.setPrefWidth(500);
        main.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        main.getChildren().addAll(head,new Separator(),performersPane,new Separator(),crewGrid,new Separator());

        //Layout of Application
        root.setCenter(preview.area());
        root.setRight(sp);
        root.setBottom(btns);

        //preview.placeCanvas();

        title.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, outFocus, inFocus) ->
        {
            if(outFocus)
            {
                preview.placeCanvas();
                Alert placed=new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION,"Placed Canvas!",ButtonType.OK);
                placed.showAndWait();
            }   
        });

        Scene ui=new Scene(root);
        main.requestFocus();
        frame.setScene(ui);
        frame.setMaximized(true);

        frame.show();
    }
}

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Preview
{
    Canvas can=new Canvas();
    GraphicsContext gc=can.getGraphicsContext2D();
    Pane canvas=new Pane();

    int WIDTH=1920;
    int HEIGHT=1080;
    int y=50;

    public Node area()
    {
        BorderPane container=new BorderPane();
        ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane(can);
        sp.setFitToHeight(true);
        sp.setFitToWidth(true);

        sp.setStyle("-fx-background: black;");
        container.setCenter(sp);
        return container;
    }

    public void placeCanvas()
    {
        can.setHeight(100);
        can.setWidth(100);
        gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        gc.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
        canvas.getChildren().add(can);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to familiarise yourself with how this site works.

Comment: Are you sure your listener is getting triggered? It will only fire if the focused property changes.

Comment: luckydog32 yes, I am sure that my listener is triggered. I used a System.out.println(); to check.

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to answer it. There could be many things wrong or missing; there's no way to tell from the code and description you have posted in the question. No-one knows where any of this code is being invoked, or how you are adding the canvas (or border pane in the first example) to the scene graph, etc. Create and post a [MCVE].

Comment: Thanks @James_D I edited my post, hoping to make things clearer and posted complete code examples.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding my pane to the scrollpane and not my Canvas.